# Youtube subscribe button not working in Angular project

Tags: angular, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to add subscribe button in one of my angular components.

So I am following the standard way provided by the [YouTube Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button) The button doesn't show up when I load the page. Is there something I am missing?

Project Specification: 
Angular 5 
Typescript 2.4

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems Like you have to append YouTube script dynamically.
You can do something like below, First paste html in your code or what ever html file.

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data- 
layout="full" data-theme="dark" data-count="default"></div>
```

> Thought you are using angular your YouTube button won't get initialized.

I have one hack for that you can dynamically append JavaScript file so that your button get's initialize.

```
const node = document.createElement('script'); 
node.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"; 
node.type = 'text/javascript';
node.async = true;
node.charset = 'utf-8';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

This will dynamically append script tag in your head and your button will get initialize.

> This approach you can use for anytime when you need to append js dynamically.
>
> ***Html code*** goes into your ***template file*** and ***JS code*** will goes into your ***init()*** function or on ***click function*** that dependence on your requirement.

Comment: @AbhilashRathod updated answer at below please check.

Comment: @AbhilashRathod ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

Include the script in index.html file

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>`

And in any component.html file put below code

`<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data- 
    layout="full" data-theme="dark" data-count="default"></div>`

You will get the element but it wont show up in some cases. Set the g-ytssubscribe position is css file.

```
.ytssubscribe{
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:200px;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid it's not working. The button doesn't seem to show as well as the iFrame in which it should load doesn't have anything. I added the libraries you mentioned as well. But, couldn't get to work.

Comment: Is the libraries present in the page you are loading in iframe. And can you confirm that you can't find any element with the class g-ytsubscribe

Comment: Yes the libraries I have loaded in the ```index.html``` and added your css class which is the only class of its name.